# I retagged a few questions with the relevant service, and the tag was later removed by a user

Tags: discussion, tags

> Disclaimer: I own the service for which I was tagging the questions with.

Recently, I encountered that a few questions were asked for (or at least around) the service I run, [JSONBin.io](https://jsonbin.io) and the tag was deleted later without any explanation by a specific user. I also tried to add data to the tag wiki, but can someone explain to me what did go wrong here that the tag was deleted?

I tagged that question as these users were interacting with the API the service provided and in some or the other way, were related to the service. I did not tag other questions where users suggested the service in the answer as the questions were not explicitly asking for JSONBin.io.

Do we consider the above as a self-promotion? But clearly, the intention here is to mark the questions with the right service. Similar to questions tagged for [CodePen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CodePen).

Examples of such questions:

- [How to get the correct URL for a JSON array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60372287/how-to-get-the-correct-url-for-a-json-array)
- [Json data fetching lag problem from jsonbin.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323095/json-data-fetching-lag-problem-from-jsonbin-io)
- [How to store and access an API secret key on your server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61585217/how-to-store-and-access-an-api-secret-key-on-your-server)
- [Load Data from JSONBin.io via using jQuery $.ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63764035/load-data-from-jsonbin-io-via-using-jquery-ajax)
- [How to pass headers in axios as secret-key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61891873/how-to-pass-headers-in-axios-as-secret-key)
- [PUT request not updating JSON when using a GET request, though it says it's successful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62093838/put-request-not-updating-json-when-using-a-get-request-though-it-says-its-succ)

Comment: Tags are not meant to be used for anything that happens to be referenced in the question. A question regarding axios that happens to use JSONBin.io as an example endpoint does not need to be tagged with [jsonbin.io]. In fact, depending on the question, it might not even need to be tagged [axios]. For instance, if the user is asking about trying to get a number of requests to be called in sequence, that really doesn't have anything to do with [axios] or [jsonbin.io], just [promises].

Comment: @HereticMonkey fair, could be one-off, but other questions are just around the API, also, the one with the Axios is around how to attach the header with a hyphen which is again specific to the service, so.

Answer (score 36):

<s>Why is this even a tag?</s>

Tags are meant to add some metadata around the *exact domain space* an OP is working in.  Tools are a domain space but it's very, very, ***very*** rare that someone would post on Stack Overflow about a specific web tool's specific problems (which, at that point, we'd just direct them to whatever help documentation is available at that site and close the question anyway; we're not here to troubleshoot someone else's website).

Phrased another way, **unless the question directly talks about using this service as an integral part of the question, meaning that the problem lies chiefly with retrieving data from JSONBin.io, it should not be tagged as such.**

In that vein, *maybe* one or two of these questions could be tagged with it, but I would have to invest some time into really proving that out.  But even still, one or two questions on this subject matter doesn't *quite* justify a whole tag for it.  Not yet, anyway.

Comment: "...one or two questions on this subject matter doesn't quite justify a whole tag for it. Not yet, anyway." Is there any guidance for when a whole tag begins to be justified? It makes sense to cut the long tail of scarcely used tags, but is there a commonly agreed upon lower bound for a tag size? If I go to the tags page and browse through the 1700 pages of tags I see at least 400 pages of tags with less than 5 questions each.

Comment: @Trilarion hence my suggestion to revamp the tag creation process, because most if not all of those <5 question tags almost certainly should not exist. That might be an alternative process to follow: if a tag hasn't accumulated X questions within Y time of its creation, said tag gets auto-burninated.